# Target a bell character with a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I noticed that there's a regular expression character for bell. I can't match though. I read what this character is on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character), but I don't understand how to find it in a regex.

```
<input type="text" value="␇" />
<input type="text" value="\a" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/umQq8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/␇/` to match `␇`, `/\\a/` to match `\a`

http://jsfiddle.net/umQq8/1/

The wikipedia article is about the bell character but the character is [`U+2407 SYMBOL FOR BELL`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2407/index.htm), not [the bell character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/07/index.htm)

In your JSFiddle, you are writing `\a` in HTML, but in HTML the backslash escapes are not interpreted in any special way. In Javascript, backslash is a meta-character but the sequence `\a` is unrecognized and it will be treated as literal backslash and a. If you want actual bel character in your form, <del>you need to write actual bel character (kinda hard because it's invisible) or `&#7;`</del> you can't because those are illegal.

Comment: I don't think he's trying to match a literal `\a` but the actual bell character for which `\a` is a shorthand.

Comment: @mart1n `\a` is literally just `\a` in html. There is no `\a` escape in javascript either. If you want your input to have actual bel character then you need to write actual bel character, or use `&#7;`

Comment: `/\a/` will match `&#7;` ?

Comment: @thomas no, `\a` is unrecognized in Javascript. `/\u0007/` will match it though

Comment: @thomas actually never mind, control characters are illegal as input values it seems

Answer (score 2):

```
str.match(/\u2407/) !== null //string contains ␇
```

Answer (score 0):

In your IF statement, you can search for either `\a` (you have that in there already and it returns true) or the `\u2407` character, which matches the bell unicode character.