# ASCII 7 bell character in in JavaScript's regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I make a ASCII 7 bell character in JavaScript's regular expressions?

My regex: `^[#&][^ \a]{0,200}$`

The regex above causes literally to not take the character `a` instead of the ASCII 7 character.

See example:  https://regex101.com/r/5nMNL4/1

Even at the explanation on the right side of Regex101 it says:

> \a matches the bell character (ASCII 7)

Comment: Javascript doesn't support the `\a` in regex, you'd have to use `\u2407` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), the `\a` modifier is not on the list of supported modifiers for regular expressions in Javascript.

If you want to match the `␇` symbol you can use `\u2407`

```js
console.log( "Test␇String".match(/\u2407/) )
```

If you want to match the bell character `&#7;` you'd use `\u0007`

```js
var s = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
console.log( s.match(/\u0007/) )
```

```html
<div id="test">&#7;test</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot write `"\a"` and expect a bell char in the string as [JS escape sequences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) do not include this one.

However, to find it in the text, use `/\x07/`:

[image]

```js
console.log(/\x07/.test("\x07"));
```

Another possible issue is that you are trying to match a [Unicode `␇` char](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2407/index.htm), then see [Target a bell character with a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018950/target-a-bell-character-with-a-regular-expression).

Comment: As a side note, **do not believe everything regex101.com tells you**, check the documentation and test your regexps in the target environment - always. Regex101 still has bugs.

Comment: I have a related question about non-printable control characters here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73633022/what-is-the-purpose-of-non-printable-control-characters-in-this-email-validation.  I think user6410654 question and your answer here are helpful in getting to the bottom of it.  Thank you! I observe that if I `console.log('\x07');` in node.js running in the macOS terminal, the computer makes a beeping sound.